# Reading a file from stdin

Tags: c, file, stdin, c-strings

It's been years since I programmed in C, and so I've been struggling a lot just to do a simply "get filename & path from stdin, read file, print file to stdout" task, which I know shouldn't be that hard but ya. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    //scanf("%s", filename);
    char *filename;
    filename = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

    read(STDIN_FILENO, filename, 200);


    printf("%s", filename);

    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        printf("File not found.");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

I my code continues to simply print out `File not found.`, when I know for a fact my file path and everything is correct (not only because I literally drop it and past it into terminal from my folder with Mac OSX El Capitan - what a lovely feature, but also) because I had a different version of this program using `scanf` which found the file and read it perfectly fine, (as you can see I have it commented out on my code).

There is another program I'm writing that just uses this one, and I got rid of the `scanf` because I think it was negatively affecting other things in that program, so I want to be able to use `read()`

If anyone has any advice on how I can fix this or why this isn't working, that would be greatly appreciated as I've been at this for hours already and would very much like to move on to my *actual* program that I need to code!

THANKS A BUNCH

Comment: You should not cast the return value of `malloc()` and it's not needed in [tag:c]. Don't use `sizeof(char)` because it adds nothing and it's always 1 and don't `malloc()` that since you can define an array for 200 chars, also read the file name with `fgets()` and drop the end line character.

Comment: when calling system function, like `malloc()`,    `read()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When displaying an error message, those error indication was returned from a call to a system function, display the error on `stderr`, along with your text and the system error message using: `perror( "your text" );`

Comment: in modern `C`, when returning from the `main()` function, if the return value is 0 then no need for the `return` statement..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must remove the `'\n'` new line character that is being read and stored into the `filename` buffer.

One of the many was to do it is include `string.h` and after reading the filename

```
char *newline = strchr(filename, '\n');
if (newline != NULL)
    *newline = '\0';
```

Also, use `fgets()` instead of `read()` because that way the program is more portable. And more importantly, `read()` will not add the `null` terminator which is very important in order to use the buffer as a string — *to pass it to `fopen()` for example* — correctly. If you want to use read try something like this

```
ssize_t length;
char filename[200];
length = read(STDIN_FILENO, filename, sizeof(filename) - 1);
if (length <= 0)
    return -1; // No input or input error
if (filename[length] == '\n')
    filename[--length] = '\0';
else
    filename[length] = '\0';
```

But otherwise, try this which is simpler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *file;
    char filename[200];
    char *newline;   

    if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1; // Input error / EOF
    newline = strchr(filename, '\n');
    if (newline) // ? is a newline present?
        *newline = '\0';
    printf("**%s**\n", filename); // ** will help checking for
                                  //    the presence of white spaces.

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file) {
        int chr;
        while ((chr = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            fputc(chr, stdout);
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        printf("File not found.");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for the edge case (newline does not exist) if you want to use `read`,
You need to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. or Put a null-terminator in the number of characters read.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY NO way! But I did forget to mention... No `calloc()` because it's precisely in this situation where it would hide a bug. It will unnecessarily initialize all bytes to `0`.

Comment: Note that using `read()` has the advantage over `fgets()` that it tells you how many bytes were read (like `getline()` does, and unlike `fgets()`), so you can check probably for the newline by indexing rather than searching.  There's an edge case where you have managed to type several lines of input before the program gets going (or you redirected standard input from a regular file); then your long `read()` could include several newlines.